# App Link is not working for Android instant app

Tags: android, google-play, android-instant-apps

I have updated my current play store app with the Instant app appLink feature. But the link is still not working after waited for 4 days.

I have created link with below steps.

Tools -> App Links Assistants
Followed all the steps and Verify that link in android studio.
It verified successfully.

I have added a dependency in app-level Gradle: implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:17.0.0"
To enable instant app right-click on app module -> Refactor -> Enable instant app support.
Increment a version code to 1 and uploaded a new build on the play store.
Could you guys please help me out to find out the missing element or a direction?

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the below developer guide for the app asset link?

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations

In that, they have mentioned the steps which have to address accordingly.

Also, you can confirm that the Digital Asset Links JSON file is properly hosted and defined using the below URL:

https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://domain.name:optional_port&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls